# Add toc in frametitle as a button

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, frame-title

I want to put my table of contents in the `frametitle` of `Madrid` theme in beamer.
so I wrote this:

```
\frametitle{\tiny 
\color{white}Introduction to Welding\qquad
\color{gray} Welding Automation and Robotics\qquad 
Research literature\qquad 
My Project}
```

[image]

as you see I add my table of contents manually in each frame and just white and gray them in each slide. 
is there anyway to make this real! it means they become real `toc` and when be clicked it shows start of section page?
any help would be appreciated.

minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
    \frame[plain]{\maketitle}
        \section{Introduction to Welding}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{\tiny \color{white}Introduction to Welding\qquad\color{gray} Welding Automation and Robotics\qquad Research literature\qquad My Project}
            \begin{block}{Introduction to Welding}
                \begin{columns}
                    \column{.3\textwidth} % Right column and width
                    \begin{itemize} 
                        \alt<1>{\color{blue}\item Introduction }{\color{gray}\item Introduction}
                        \alt<2>{\color{blue}\item Welding Defined}{\color{gray}\item  Welding Defined}
                    \end{itemize}
                    \column{.5\textwidth} % Right column and width
                \end{columns}
            \end{block} 
        \end{frame}
        \section{Welding Automation and Robotics}
        \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{\tiny\color{gray}Introduction to Welding\qquad\color{white} Welding Automation and Robotics\qquad\color{gray}Research literature\qquad My Project}
            \begin{block}{Introduction to Welding}
                \begin{columns}
                    \column{.3\textwidth} % Right column and width
                    \begin{itemize} 
                        \alt<1>{\color{blue}\item Introduction }{\color{gray}\item Introduction}
                        \alt<2>{\color{blue}\item Welding Defined}{\color{gray}\item  Welding Defined}
                    \end{itemize}
                    \column{.5\textwidth} % Right column and width
                \end{columns}
            \end{block} 
            \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter  tnx,a few mins just let me do it

Comment: There are many theme which include a build in navigation headline, have a look at https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Comment: Basically choose any theme other than madrid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the outer theme `miniframes` in combination with `\section`s to let `beamer` automatically generate a headline of all sections with clickable hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to Welding}
\frame{Introduction to Welding}
\section{Welding Automation and Robotics}
\frame{Welding Automation and Robotic}
\section{Research literature}
\frame{Research literatur}
\section{My Project}
\frame{My Project}
\end{document}
```

Resulting headline:

[image: headline for the example document]

Comment: how can I prevent it on my `\maketitle` page and next page `\tableofcontents` (second page is not very important)

Comment: As in your MWE, you could use a `plain` frame, i.e. `\frame[plain]{\maketitle}` and `\frame[plain]{\tableofcontents}`. This will remove both the head- and the footline. If you really only want to remove the headline, but keep the footline, you can temporarily blank the headline and free the space it occupies by doing something like `{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}\frame{\vspace*{-\headheight}\maketitle}}` (not recommended).