# create a command with optional argument

Tags: beamer, macros

as you know if we want use an alternative statement on beamer we can use:

```
\alt<overlay specification>{default text}{alternative text}<overlay specification>
```

in my case I  always use this format:

```
\alt<#1>{\color{blue}\item #2 }{\color{gray}\item #2}
```

where #1 is frame numbers (like 1 or 1-3) and its default value is `+(1)`
and  #2 is my alternative text.

I've tried this code:

```
\newcommand\a[2]{\alt<#1>{\color{blue}\item #2 }{\color{gray}\item #2}}
```

it works but as you know this is not an optional command, I want to make #1 be an optional argument of my command with  `+(1)` as a default value.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by the way as I run it first time it said  command `\a` is already defined! I did not define this command before so I used `\renewcommand\a`. I have no idea about what was `\a` is by default  is anyone know?

Comment: Can you please tell us what the command should do? I guess there might be an easier way then a newcommand...

Comment: @samcarter I used this way in this minimal [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390253/add-toc-in-frametitle-as-a-button), I would be appreciated if you run this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to uncover you items:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+>]
      \item Introduction
      \item Welding Define
       \item Welding Define
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want first Item be off in second frame, and cause I used multi photo in next column sometimes I need one Item be 'on'(not off) for multi frames.

Comment: @asys See my edit, the first item is switched off again. If one item should be visible for more then one slide, you can always fine control the appearance with `\item<3-5> text`